Are conversation laws equivalent to the non-existence of certain waves in the associated field?
If conservation of mass-energy were to be violated in a spherically symmetric way (eg a non-rotating black hole suddenly appears), the change in spacetime geometry would spread outwards as a gravitational wave. However, since in GR there are no spherically symmetric gravitational waves, such a change could not propagate.
Is that an accurate statement?
If so, is the converse accurate?
Would it be correct to say that the conservation law and the non-existence of such a type of wave are equivalent statements?
And in the unlikely event that all of that is true for gravitation, are there corresponding equivalences for other/all conservation laws (eg electric charge appearing would cause a longitudinal vacuum electromagnetic wave)?
If any or all of this is incorrect, what have I gotten wrong?

This doesn't make any sense - black holes, like any other physical objects, don't "suddenly appear" and it is entirely unclear what you mean by this change "propagating".

This is what irritates me about stack exchange. If anyone tries to ask a question which employs an unconventional point of view, the response from moderators is "I don't understand this, so it must be worthless."

As an attempt to explain, the whole point of the question is to ask whether physical conservation laws can be reformulated as constraints on what types of waves can and can't exist in physical fields. Obviously matter doesn't appear out of nowhere. Also, less obviously, gravitational waves cannot be spherically symmetric. I was hoping that someone who knows more physics than I do would have the opportunity to comment on what relationship may exist between those two facts. Closing the question seconds after it was posted removes that possibility. Downvoting it was just adding insult to injury.

Please edit your question with clarifications instead of adding them in the comments (editing a question allows you to automatically enqueue it for review to be reopened). As for the content of the comment: Please explain where you see the relation between conservation laws and fields, especially considering that conservation laws also exist in classical particle mechanics by the same mechanism (Noether's theorem) where there are no fields.
